# Writing a Test for an API call with Http CallableContext using Mocha in Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

I have the following method

```
async addNonAppUserToGroup(
  data: any,
  context: functions.https.CallableContext
) {
  const userId = context.auth?.uid ?? context.auth?.token.user_id;
  functions.logger.debug(`Requested by ${userId}`, data);
}
```

Now i want to write a spec test file for this method. and i have the following

```
const callableContext: CallableContext = {
  rawRequest: undefined,
  auth: {
    uid: "somFaciliatator",
  } as AuthData,
};

it("should call method", async () => {
  const data = {
    users: [
      {
        "firstName": "Sky",
        "lastName": "Stars",
      },
    ],
  };
      
  const service = new GroupService(admin.firestore(), {
    userId: "someFacilitator",
    admin,
  });
  
  await service.addNonAppUserToGroup(data, callableContext);
});
```

In my code, i get an error that says

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Request'.ts(2322)
> https.d.ts(84, 5): The expected type comes from property 'rawRequest' which is declared here on type 'CallableContext'

I have tried multiple ways to try to resolve this error so that i can run the test but all to no avail. Not sure if anyone knows how to write tests for a CallableContext class in typescript.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you can't just put `undefined` into `rawRequest`.  You need a Request type object that describes the HTTP request being sent to the function.

Comment: You might be helped by knowing that there is a whole separate library provided by Firebase for testing functions, and it does a lot of a heavy lifting on the details so you don't have to worry about implementing the implementation details. You should consider using this instead. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing